# awk to process very large file

Tags: awk, performance

I have a file here where I want to tag each line with FILEB and FILEC as references.

If column 1 of fileb or filec  is in column 2 of filea, get the column 2 of fileb or filec (if column 1 file c not equal to 63), else print 'others' (see OUTPUT1).

The final output would be the sum of column 4 (group by column 2 & 5 of OUTPUT1) and count per column 5 (OUTPUT 1).

FILEA

```
 63,234111,000,2
 63,234111,111,3
 56,456711,000,2
 63,678999,111,1
```

FILEB

```
 234,XXX
 456,ZZZ
```

FILEC

```
 4567,YYY
 234,GGG
```

OUTPUT1

```
 63,234111,000,2,XXX
 63,234111,111,3,XXX
 56,456711,000,2,YYY
 63,678999,111,1,OTHERS
```

FINAL

```
 C1, C2,     C3,  SUM of C4, XXX, ZZZ, YYY, GGG, OTHERS
 63, 234111, 000, 5,         2,   0,   0,   0,   0
 56, 456111, 000, 2,         0,   0,   1,   0,   0
 63, 678999, 111, 1,         0,   0,   0,   0,   1
```

I have a scripts here but too slow to process very large file.

```
##tagging (ref fileb)

awk -F~ 'NR==FNR {a[$1+0]=$2;next} $1+0==63 {print $0"~"a[$2+0]}' fileb filea > OUTPUT

##tagging (ref filea)

awk -F~ 'NR==FNR {a[$1+0]=$2;next} $1+0!~63 {print $0,a[$2+0]}' filec OUTPUT > OUTPUT

##tagging others

awk -F~ '{if ($5 == "") print $0,"OTHERS"}' > OUTPUT

##sum and count

awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP="~"}{arr[$2,$5]+=$4 }{arr2[$2,$5]++}END {for (i in arr) print i,arr[i],arr2[i]}'
```

Comment: How large is "very large"? TB? PB?

Comment: its 50GB but processing the file with the 1st awk script alone took me 2hrs.

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot of conversion between numbers and strings in your first awk script. What happens if you take out the two `+0` adjustments to the indexes? Which version of awk are you using? We should be able to avoid 200GB of i/o by processing the tagging of both fileb and filec and OTHERS at the same time. Depending on how many distinct values there are it might be possible to remove another 100GB. How fast are your disks - is this a server class machine with ssd's? Just using unix pipes might reduce the overall job time from 6 hours to 1 if this is disk bound.

Comment: removing the +0 saved me about 8% time, not as much as I expected. Switching from GNU awk 4.1.3 to mawk doubled the speed.